# Neat/compact C code for working with multiple GPIO ports on a microcontroller

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, avr

I'm writing a program where I need to control many output pins on my Atmega4809. How can I work with these without having to write duplicate code (using loops and arrays for example)?

Instead of doing this...

```
PORTA.OUT |= (1 << PIN2);
PORTB.OUT |= (1 << PIN4);
PORTC.OUT |= (1 << PIN1);
PORTD.OUT |= (1 << PIN3);
```

.. I want to do something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    myPorts[i].OUT |= (1 << myPins[i];
}
```

I tried to `#define` all the ports and pins, and putting them in arrays like this:
(for context the output pins are connected to rows and columns of an LED_matrix)

```
#define COL0_PORT PORTF
#define COL1_PORT PORTD
#define COL2_PORT PORTA
#define COL3_PORT PORTB

PORT_t col_ports[] = {COL0_PORT, COL1_PORT, COL2_PORT, COL3_PORT};
```

When building, I get "initializer element is not constant".

Comment: Why couldn't you simply do `PORT_t col_ports[] = { PORTA, PORTB, PORTC, PORTD }`?  But intuitively, I feel like this should be an array of `PORT_t` pointers.  What does `PORT_t` look like?

Comment: **WHY?!?**  The amount of time spent actually writing code is only a small portion of the effort.  Write clear code that's easy to understand.  If it takes more lines to do that - that is what you do.  Cramming as much code into as few lines as possible is nothing more than a way to write code that's bug-prone and hard to understand.  Look at how much effort you're already spending trying to change code that's clear and apparently working just fine.  **If** you can refactor it into something simpler (as @RobertHarvey suggests) then you do it.  You don't do it just because it's shorter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I could do that, of course, I just thought it was more readable. I'm including `<avr/io.h>` where `PORT_t` is defined. `PORT_t` is just a struct with a bunch of  `register8_t` elements, including the `OUT`. ´PORT_F` looks like this: `#define PORTF (*(PORT_t *) 0x04A0)`. I still get the same error when initializing the array like you suggested.

Comment: @AndrewHenle firstly it's about learning. I'd like to understand why I can/can't do stuff, not only find a way that works. Secondly, the original solution is not very useful, for example if I want to make a function `setPixel()`

Comment: Since your question is about the error message, we need code that reproduces the error message.  See "How can I create a [mcve]?"

Comment: You want an array of `PORT_t *` [i.e. pointers]. See: http://leoninstruments.blogspot.com/2014/04/xmega-tutorial-new-methods-of-registers.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it does not get more readable than your original code, beyond that it just gets less readable and maintainable.  the compiler is going to generate what it generates, dont make it work harder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that variables like `PORTA` have type `PORT_t`, then you can store pointers to them in an array using this syntax:

```
PORT_t * col_ports[] = { &PORTA, &PORTA, &PORTF, &PORTB };
```

You might try putting the `const` keyword right before `col_ports` as well; that might move the array to flash, thus saving you some RAM space.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 8 bit MCU with 16 bit register map, then your ports will be defined in a register map along the lines of this:

```
#define PORTA (*(volatile uint8_t*)0x1234u)
```

Why is explained here: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

You will want an array of `volatile uint8_t*` pointers: `volatile uint8_t* col_ports[]`. However, you most likely also want this array to be allocated in flash not RAM, therefore add `const` *after* the `*`, to make the array itself read-only:

```
volatile uint8_t* const col_ports[] =
{
  &PORTA,
  &PORTB,
  &PORTC
};
```

There might also be various memory mapping hiccups related to the old AVR Harvard architecture, so you might have to add `PROGMEM` after the `const`, or similar compiler-specific non-standard keywords.